# How to create a loop for shapiro.test

Tags: r

I would like to create a loop for these test, but I can't use "table1:table10), any suggestions?

```
shapiro.test(table1)
shapiro.test(table2)
shapiro.test(table3)
shapiro.test(table4)
shapiro.test(table5)
shapiro.test(table6)
shapiro.test(table7)
shapiro.test(table8)
shapiro.test(table9)
shapiro.test(table10)
```

Comment: Try `lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "^table\\d+$")), shapiro.test)`. If not working please share sample data.

Comment: You've already made a little mistake - instead of creating 10 objects with names like that, you should have put them in a list, then you can get `table[[i]]` and do a loop over `i` from 1 to 10 using `lapply` or `for`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
  print(shapiro.test(eval(parse(text=paste("table", i, sep = "")))))
}
```